Ambiguous routing need explanation as to why
I have a controller with several public methods in ASP.NET Core 8:
<HttpPost("{methName?}">
Public Async Function HttpPost(methName As String) As Task(Of IActionResult)

then several other public methods like this that I don't want as endpoints without routing attributes
Public Sub Foo()

When I execute a POST request to the URL domain/controllerName/method, all works OK. The HttpPost method gets executed as expected.
When I execute a request to the URL domain/controllerName, I get an ambiguity error stating that HttpPost and all my other public functions without http attributes are now not only candidates for routing but they all match and can't resolve
I get that public members are automatically candidates for endpoint actions but none of them actually match. Foo and all my other method names don't match with anything. The only thing that matches is again the HttpPost method that has a configured route to take no argument.
And yes I know you can mark methods with [NonAction] and use Order = -1 to solve the ambiguity but I need to know why this absurd behavior.

Is your project asp.net core MVC or API?

It's neither just a blank ASP.NET project and I added a class inheriting from base controller.

Can you please share a full [mre]?

Just make a Controller inheriting from a ControllerBase with the two functions I listed above. No routing in startup. Only attribute routing shown above. That's it.

When the routing middleware executes, it sets the Endpoint and routes the value from the current request to the Endpoint on the HttpContext
During the route matching process, ASP.NET Core finds all possible matching endpoints based on the requested URL and routing configuration. The route matching is carried out in stages, and each stage will filter out qualified endpoints. EndpointSelector is the last stage of route matching. In this stage, the framework selects the highest priority endpoint from all matching endpoints as the final match. If only one endpoint has the highest priority, then this endpoint will be selected as the best match. However, if there are multiple endpoints with the same highest priority, the framework cannot determine which endpoint should be selected, and an ambiguous matching exception will be thrown.
For details, you can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#url-matching

I don't get how this applies to my scenario. There is only one match in my scenario. There is no ambiguity.
